# If $\operatorname{tr}(A)=\operatorname{tr}(A^2)=0$ for $A\in M_3(\Bbb F)$, prove $A^3=cI$ for some scalar $c$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Does anyone have any creative ideas to prove the following?

> Let $A \in M_3(\Bbb F)$ be such that $\operatorname{tr}(A) = \operatorname{tr}(A^2) = 0$. Prove that $A^3 = cI$ for some scalar $c$.

I prove that for $A \in M_3(\Bbb F)$,
$$A^3-\operatorname{tr}(A)A^2+\operatorname{tr}(\operatorname{Adj}(A))A-\det(A)I_3 =0$$

Then $tr(A^3)=3det (A)$

I found this problem in a practice guide about Cayley-Hamilton Theorem.

I want to know if there is any property that helps me solve this problem in a shorter way, because working with variables is very long and I don't get anywhere.

Comment: Note that askers are expected to provide context for their questions, [as is explained here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Please [edit] your question to tell us where you encountered this problem, what you have tried so far, and any other thoughts you have about the question.

Comment: Try to show your attempt.

Comment: This is true only if the characteristic of $\mathbb F$ is not $2$. For a counterexample, consider the companion matrix of $x^3+x+1$ over $\mathbb F=GF(2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3$ are the eigenvalues of $A$, then
$$
\mathrm{Tr}\,A=0\quad\Longrightarrow\quad \lambda_1+\lambda_2+\lambda_3=0. \qquad (1)
$$
and
$$
\mathrm{Tr}\,A^2=0\quad\Longrightarrow\quad \lambda_1^2+\lambda_2^2+\lambda_3^2=0. \qquad(2)
$$
Now, in case the characteristic of $\mathbb F$ is not 2, combining (1) & (2) we obtain
$$
\lambda_1\lambda_2+\lambda_2\lambda_3+\lambda_3\lambda_1=0
$$
and hence the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is of the form:
$$
p_A(\lambda)=-(\lambda^3-a_2\lambda^2+a_1\lambda+a_0)=-\lambda^3+a_0,
$$
since $a_2=\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\lambda_3$ and $a_1=\lambda_1\lambda_2+\lambda_2\lambda_3+\lambda_3\lambda_1$.

Thus, due to [Cayley-Hamilton Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem), $$-A^3+a_0I=0.$$

Comment: I guess you are assuming the characteristic to be different from $2$, right? Otherwise I only manage to get $$2\lambda_1 \lambda_2 + 2\lambda_2 \lambda_3+2\lambda_3 \lambda_1=0.$$